# Strange behavior from variable-gain amplifier

Tags: amplifier, filter, pwm, buffer

Sorry, this might not go anywhere. My first SE question, though, on any site.

I've built at least three distinct audio amplifiers with the [TDA7056B](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/TDA7056B.pdf), which is a really great amp. It takes a voltage between 0.4 and 1.2 V on pin 5 to control its gain. In the first two versions of the circuit, I used logic ICs and/or counters and an op amp with a resistor network for a DAC to provide the voltage, and all worked well. This last week, I decided to try my hand at doing the same with an Arduino doing the logic work, and instead of an op amp DAC, I'm filtering a PWM signal and feeding it to a darlington-pair voltage follower. It took a while to get it right, but now it works. The odd part is, the voltage range that produces the correct gain variation is completely different: *1.22 V to 2.25 V*. I'm happy that it works, but I'm very curious as to why that is.

The linked data sheet has all the information I have as to the voltage control and everything. Here's what the filter and voltage follower looks like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1odGF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, as for what I've tried/thought of:

I *have* taken into account that there's a voltage drop accross the darlington pair. I'm measuring at the pin.

I checked the voltage with an oscilloscope, and while it is noisy, there doesn't seem to be anything of the PWM signal in there.

I tried switching the IC with another on hand, and it works the same.

My current theory is that it has something to do with the way the pin interacts with the circuit. Perhaps it's not exactly the voltage *at* the pin, rather the current that flows in or out at that pin (which varies between +/- 25 µA), and perhaps this solution does something different about that.

So, why is the voltage not what's described in the data sheet? What did I do differently?

Answer (score 1):

I think the clue is that you see noise on pin 5.  I suspect C4 is open and that a 1 kΩ resistive impedance is not sufficient to hold the pin at a steady level.  As a result, the input is oscillating or doing other strange stuff, which results in a different volume level for the same average DC level.

Hold a 10 µF or so cap between pin 5 and ground and see what that does.  If there is still noise on the pin, then read the datasheet carefully about what filtering and possibly minimum capacitance is supposed to be on that pin.  If everything works as expected with the 10 µF cap there, then either just go with that or check the connections to the 1 µF cap.  You might find a bad solder joint or ground connection.

Comment: Thanks, I don't mean to ignore your answer, but I wanted to test it first. I haven't had time yet to try a different capacitor, but I'm pretty sure that the noise was not that large. In the data sheet, 1uF is the recommended setup, but I'll try it just in case. As for the resistor, I think that it should be more than enough because the current in or out of that pin doesn't exceed 25uA...